# Hadoop 2.6.0 wordcount example running forever

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I started all the daemons in my hadoop 2.6.0 machine on ububtu 14.4 LTS

```
vaibhav@vaibhav-300E4Z-300E5Z-300E7Z:~$ jps
5644 NodeManager
10116 Jps
9602 SecondaryNameNode
5324 ResourceManager
8001 JobHistoryServer
9402 DataNode
9237 NameNode
```

and then ran the below commend  to run wordcount program from hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar.

```
vaibhav@vaibhav-300E4Z-300E5Z-300E7Z:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce$ hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar wordcount /data1 /data1/output
```

and it was running forever. How can it be resolved?

Comment: Assuming it is a single node setup what did you put in yarn-site.xml?

Comment: can you share the logs to trace out the issue ?

Comment: @AntarikshaYelkawar yes it is a single node setup

Comment: It has been a long time... anyway try to run the wordcount program given in the tutorial and not the examples